# Creating new Invite Type

Tags: 7

When trying to create new invite type from *admin/structure/invite-types/add* I get this response:

> Sorry no Invitation Type modules available in the system.

I has been researching and there is no info referral to this. And I can not create that invitation type from anywhere, also there is no info to do it programmatically.
I get lost into code module but [this](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/invite/tree/includes/invite.admin.inc?id=bf1f731823a9fe742e4dd3e8716da10fea82e73a#n28) is the line that returns that message.

Comment: What version of the Invite module (https://www.drupal.org/project/invite) are you using? Are you sure everything is properly enabled and installed?

Comment: Version 7.x-4.0-beta2 and no requirements unmet on modules page.

Comment: Solved.
When installed **Invite by e-mail** module got that Invite type, there was no requirement to install but it is in fact required.

Comment: please answer your own question so it is marked as answered ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is required Invite by e-mail module, it provides an Invite Type.